# Removing a node from DOM

Tags: java, dom

I wrote this program to remove a node from tree, but it still exists!

How come this happenes? After printing the node content, it still shows the same content as before deleting it, which means it still exist!

Code:

```
 public class JavaApplication38 {
   public static void check(Node node){


       if (node == null || node.getNodeName() == null)
    return;



  check(node.getFirstChild());  

System.out.println(node.getNodeValue() != null && node.getNodeValue().trim().length() == 0 ? "" : node);
  if (  "abcd".equals(node.getTextContent()))
      node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
    check(node.getNextSibling());  

}
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {


     File file = new File("d:\\a.xml");
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document document = db.parse(file);
  document.getDocumentElement().normalize();




  Node b=document.getFirstChild();


  check(b);
  check(b);

    }

 }
```

Comment: Wait, Java too has this stupid `node.parentNode.removeChild( node )` pattern?

Comment: @Šime: If you use the Java implementation of the DOM API, you will of course have to live with all the flaws in the DOM API. But there are usually better alternatives for XML processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The node is deleted from the Tree, but it does exist as a node, with no parent. after removing child, do this again

```
d=document.getElementsByTagName("data1");

b=d.item(0);
System.out.println(b.getTextContent());
```

You wont get the same text content (if different `data1` tags have different contents).

Answer (score 2):

No, the node *is* removed.
Removing the node from the tree does automatically delete it.

To see if the node is properly removed, you could write some code for printing the tree.

EDIT:
I'm not sure if your `check` method visits every node in the tree.
And I would suggest separating the code that prints the tree from the code that modifies it; then call

```
  printTree(d);
  modifyTree(d);
  printTree(d);
```

You seem to know and understand recursion, so you should be able to write a method that prints the tree.

Comment: there is a recursive function to traverse the tree then i check if the node content equals to **abcd** which is the text content of **data1** i print it twice but both are same. is there anything with my code then?
'public static void check(Node node){
     if (node == null || node.getNodeName() == null)
   return;
 if (  "abcd".equals(node.getTextContent()))
   node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
 check(node.getFirstChild());  
System.out.println(node.getNodeValue() != null && node.getNodeValue().trim().length() == 0 ? "" : node);
    check(node.getNextSibling());}'

Comment: So, it's not solved yet? Then I suggest you update the question.

Comment: i made the changes, ow about now?

Comment: i know what you mean about seperating it, but the point is that the function **check** is traversing tree in postorder fashion, then i would like whenever during traversing, it found a secefic value, then delete its node.is that going to happen in my code?